# CSS animation propblem

Tags: css

I have added an animation, when the text is longer. The animation needs to move the from right to left until the whole text is wheeling left.
So here is a part of css code:

```
@keyframes scrollm {                                                                                                                                                                                      
     0% {                                                                                                                                                                                                  
         transform: translate(0%, 0);                                                                                                                                                                      
     }                                                                                                                                                                                                     
     100% {transform: translate(-100%, 0%)}                                                                                                                                                                
 }
```

and I'm using here:

```
  #someDiv:hover{                                                                                                                                
     display: inline-block;                                                                                                                                                                                
     padding-left:100%;                                                                                                                                                                                    
     -webkit-animation: scrollm 6s infinite linear;                                                                                                                                                        
     -moz-animation: scrollm 6s infinite linear;                                                                                                                                                           
     animation: scrollm 6s infinite linear;                                                                                                                                                                
 }
```

So now, the problem is, the speed is different for different text length.
How can I fix his problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You've defined the speed to be `6s` long, so that will be the same everywhere.  What you are seeing might be that different sized elements move at different velocities to get from point A to point B over the `6s` time duration.

Comment: I see, the speed time I defined as 6s, but I suppose that the different speed move is for transformation when I'm using percentage.

Comment: moving 100% of a 10px wide element will move faster than moving the same distance for a 1000px wide element.  The left side is closer to the end point fr one of those, so it has less distance to cover than the other in the same 6s time span.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually set the width of the element (or set it to `display: block`), the scroll speed will match up. So something like:

```css
#someDiv {
  /* % or px value, whatever makes sense for your use case: */
  width: 100%;
  /* if you want the text on one line: */
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: It works. but now it does not show whole text. It is scrolling not to the end of text